# How to edit xrandr code so you can place in into xorg.conf?

Tags: xorg, 19.04, xrandr, syslinux

Could anybody help me format this, so I can put it into my `xorg.conf`?

```bash
function run {
if ! pgrep $1 ; then
    $@&
fi
}

if xrandr | grep -q 'DP-1 connected' ; then
   xrandr --output eDP-1 --off
fi
```

Comment: Rather than stating it must be in `xorg.conf` it would be better to request it runs on startup. Also there is a flaw when external monitor is disconnected the internal monitor isn't turned back on. Lastly the function `run` would probably be best placed in `~/.bashrc` file.